# Java: Array and using ++ operator when adding values

Tags: java, arrays, operators

How exactly does the `++` operator work when added to a normal array of ints like this `myArray[range]++;`

if I got a selection of values (range) being added iteratively `1,2,3,3,3,4,4` will it add `1` once, `2` once, `3` three times and `4` two times? And does it just add it to the end of the array?

Comment: There is no *adding an element to a Java array*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myArray[range]++;` will increment the value at index `range`. If you want to increment all values do -

```
 for (int i = 0; i < MyArray.Length; i++)
      MyArray[i]++;
```

Answer (score 5):

int myArray[range]++; Will increment 1 to the element in the position range.

To increment all the element in the array you just have to do:

```
for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    myArray[i]++;
```

Answer (score 2):

> myArray[range]++

This would simply increment the value at the index `range` in the `int` array `myArray`.

Answer (score 1):

`myArray[range]++` will add the value at the index like the other ppl mentioned. in your example, you will get:

`2,3,4,4,4,5,5`

if you used `range` as the "iterator"

Answer (score -1):

equivalent to

```
myArray[range] = myArray[range] + 1;
```

Comment: What about `value = myArray[range]++` vs. `value = (myArray[range] = myArray[range] + 1)` (and `value = (myArray[range] += 1)`?

Comment: @greybeard it will be better if you explain this in separate answer then just mentioning it in comment.